# Tools for comparing jinja2 template to rendered output for compliance?

Tags: jinja2

Are there existing tools for comparing a resulting file or string against a Jinja2 template to determine if that resulting file or string complies with the template?  Essentially, I want a check that will ensure that the rendered output hasn't been modified in some other area where the template is not variable. Any tools for this?